# Lua - Splitting string but allowing empty values

Tags: regex, string, lua, expression

I'm using lua to try and split a string by = but if a string has multiple equals signs in a row then there is an issue where it only splits it once. I need to split the string multiple times (giving '' as the "word") so that when using table.concat I can get back the exact string again.

```
function string.split(str, sep)
    if sep == nil then
        sep = "%s"
    end

    local t={}

    for str in string.gmatch(str, '[^' .. sep .. ']+') do
        table.insert(t, str)
    end

    return t
end
```

Is the function I am using.

Using `dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093==` will only let me get back `dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093=` when using `table.concat`.

Comment: `for str in (str.."="):gmatch"(.-)=" do`

Comment: I guess all you need is replace `+` with `*`, `for str in string.gmatch(str, '[^' .. sep .. ']*') do`. See https://ideone.com/T744ho

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Your code works incorrectly in LuaJIT, Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2